# Easy pythonic way to classify columns in groups and store it in Dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
    Machine_number  Machine_Running_Hours
0              1.0                  424.0
1              2.0                  458.0
2              3.0                  465.0
3              4.0                  446.0
4              5.0                  466.0
5              6.0                  466.0
6              7.0                  445.0
7              8.0                  466.0
8              9.0                  447.0
9             10.0                  469.0
10            11.0                  467.0
11            12.0                  449.0
12            13.0                  436.0
13            14.0                  465.0
14            15.0                  463.0
15            16.0                  372.0
16            17.0                  460.0
17            18.0                  450.0
18            19.0                  467.0
19            20.0                  463.0
20            21.0                  205.0
```

I am trying to classify according to machine number. Like Machine_number 1 to 5 will be one group. Then 6 to 10 in one group and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need substract `1` by [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) and then [`floordiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.floordiv.html):

```
df['g'] = df.Machine_number.sub(1).floordiv(5)
#same as //
#df['g'] = df.Machine_number.sub(1) // 5
print (df)
    Machine_number  Machine_Running_Hours    g
0              1.0                  424.0 -0.0
1              2.0                  458.0  0.0
2              3.0                  465.0  0.0
3              4.0                  446.0  0.0
4              5.0                  466.0  0.0
5              6.0                  466.0  1.0
6              7.0                  445.0  1.0
7              8.0                  466.0  1.0
8              9.0                  447.0  1.0
9             10.0                  469.0  1.0
10            11.0                  467.0  2.0
11            12.0                  449.0  2.0
12            13.0                  436.0  2.0
13            14.0                  465.0  2.0
14            15.0                  463.0  2.0
15            16.0                  372.0  3.0
16            17.0                  460.0  3.0
17            18.0                  450.0  3.0
18            19.0                  467.0  3.0
19            20.0                  463.0  3.0
20            21.0                  205.0  4.0
```

If need store in dictionary use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `dict comprehension`:

```
dfs = {i:g for i, g in df.groupby(df.Machine_number.astype(int).sub(1).floordiv(5))}
print (dfs)
{0:    Machine_number  Machine_Running_Hours
0             1.0                  424.0
1             2.0                  458.0
2             3.0                  465.0
3             4.0                  446.0
4             5.0                  466.0, 1:    Machine_number  Machine_Running_Hours
5             6.0                  466.0
6             7.0                  445.0
7             8.0                  466.0
8             9.0                  447.0
9            10.0                  469.0, 2:     Machine_number  Machine_Running_Hours
10            11.0                  467.0
11            12.0                  449.0
12            13.0                  436.0
13            14.0                  465.0
14            15.0                  463.0, 3:     Machine_number  Machine_Running_Hours
15            16.0                  372.0
16            17.0                  460.0
17            18.0                  450.0
18            19.0                  467.0
19            20.0                  463.0, 4:     Machine_number  Machine_Running_Hours
20            21.0                  205.0}
```

```
print (dfs[0])
   Machine_number  Machine_Running_Hours
0             1.0                  424.0
1             2.0                  458.0
2             3.0                  465.0
3             4.0                  446.0
4             5.0                  466.0

print (dfs[1])
   Machine_number  Machine_Running_Hours
5             6.0                  466.0
6             7.0                  445.0
7             8.0                  466.0
8             9.0                  447.0
9            10.0                  469.0
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way so that i can store groups as a dictionary?